# Standard way of parsing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I'm working on a project for my university in which i need to parse an html string into a document and add the children elements in the existing page. I have to use **Javascript 1.6 with DOM Level
3** and the project must work with **Firefox 32.0** and **Chrome 37.0.2062.120**, pretty old browsers. The problem is i have to use **only standard** methods and properties so i can't use *innerHTML*. These are my attempts so far:

I managed to parse html using the **DOMParser** object but i'm not sure if i'm allowed to use that (i found [this document](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-LS-20030619/load-save.html#LS-DOMParser) but it's not clear to me if DOMParser is standard or not), if this was the case it looks like the best option to me.

I also tried to parse html using:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(title);
doc.open(); 
doc.writeln(html); 
doc.close();
```

The problem with this method is that it doesn't work with the version of mozilla i need to use. I also tried to use the document inside a dummy iframe pointing to *about:blank* but chrome then prevents me (for security reasons i believe) to add event handlers to any of the elements coming from that document, and i need to do that.

Comment: Where are you seeing that `innerHTML` is non-standard? It's in [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-innerHTML) although I can't find where this document mentions the version.

Comment: Well, MDN [currently lists it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) as "Working Draft". Does that count as standard? There's also [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) but it falls in the same category.

Comment: @Vilx- Yeah..that's confusing, but `innerHTML` has existed for many years. I think that just means it hasn't been deprecated either... it's *still* part of the current spec.

Comment: In the project specifications that my professor gave me it's clearly stated that innerHTML it's not standard and I'm not allowed to use it, I don't know if it is the truth but I can't use it anyway.

Comment: Hah...well alright then, but that's complete rubbish from a practical standpoint. [It's been supported forever](https://caniuse.com/#search=innerhtml).

Comment: Hmm... well, the [current spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/) certainly includes it, so your prof is wrong, but... if it's explicitly forbidden, then I guess you can't use it.

Comment: Is `document.write` allowed? You can stuff your HTML into the DOM that way.

Comment: I know, this is clear example of bad teaching and I have to learn something that is already old

Comment: I don't know if working draft counts as standard, but I'd say it likely doesn't

Comment: Well, as I said, the current spec (not just the draft) includes it. But kudos about the `document.write()` idea - that's been in the standard [since DOM Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/DOM2-HTML.html). Also, it's so archaic and unwieldy that nobody in their right mind uses it anymore... but maybe it can work.

Comment: @mpen i should be allowed to use it but document.write would completly wipe the current content so its not practical

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what "JavaScript 1.6" even means, since I'm pretty sure the standard is actually called ECMA Script. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history), JS 1.6 is equal to ECMA-262 3rd edition + array extras + array and string generics + E4X. So...you should be able to use [everything in this document](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) from 1999.

Comment: Your profession should be fired. He probably hasn't updated his information since the 90s. Or you misunderstood the project specifications. In fact `innerHTML` is one of the most used JavaScript properties for manipulating the DOM, and it is supported by all browsers.

Comment: @RacilHilan, i know this is nonsense, but i didn't misunderstood the specifications i'm sure of that

Comment: @PHPglue - I don't think it's about "not supporting" rather than about "keeping things clean and standardized". Web is this weird place where some things first get wide support and only then get standardized. It's gotten a lot better lately though.

Comment: @FrancescoGalisi Not true.. `document.write` won't wipe the content. See here: http://jsbin.com/hoqucifaqa/1/edit?html,css,console,output

Comment: @PHPglue TextNode is no good... it won't interpret/parse the HTML

Comment: @mpen it looks like you're right, i'll consider using document.write then, thanks

Comment: @mpen i'm confused now: `The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.` [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Comment: @mpen as it turns out i was right, in the example you provided it didn't wipe the content because the page was not fully loaded. check this [Test](http://jsbin.com/dojipiqoce/edit?html,css,console,output)

Comment: @FrancescoGalisi Uh... I don't know if "fully loaded" is the right wording -- you've taken it out of context... it doesn't run inline anymore. As in, it doesn't execute as soon as the `<script>` tag is hit, which means it won't write into the part of the DOM where the `<script>` tag is. Now that you mention it though... I think I hit this problem a few years ago when we switched some of scripts to run asynchronously, everything broke.

Comment: @mpen well, in my project the content is added asynchronously, so it's of no use for me, thanks anyway

Comment: @FrancescoGalisi I think I made a mistake in the accepted answer. See below for details.